# Port 465 - not working in GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a vm running ubuntu server in GCP. In the GCP firewall I created a rule to enable incoming traffic on port 465, but when I telnet to my ip with that port, I get an error and can not connect. My ubuntu firewall is disabled.

I use phpmailer in a web app that I have on this server. What's the problem here ? As I understand it, by default, this port is enabled.

---

This is my ubuntu firewall configuration:

[image]

GGP firewall configuration:

[image]

and the result of the commands you gave me:

[image]

I look forward to your comments. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Google [blocks some traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic) due to the risk of abuse. Running your own mail server in GCP is pointless unless you just need to receive emails (you won't be able to send them though).**

See the [documentation about sending out emails from GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#using_standard_email_ports):

> By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports
> except port 25, which is blocked because of the risk of abuse. All
> other ports are open, including ports 587 and 465.

It's best to use a 3rd party solutions to send out emails - such as MailJet or SendGrid.

> In addition to using standard email ports, having a trusted
> third-party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet relieves
> Compute Engine and you from maintaining IP reputation with your
> receivers.

[Here's some more info how to set them up](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#email_custom_port).

Have a look at my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832112/12257250).

**However - given your case - you should have been able to connect** but you'd have to post more details about your server configuration to troubleshoot this.

You can check if the port is open with `nmap -p 465 EXTERNAL_IP_VM`; you should see something like this:

```
wb@cloudshell:~$ nmap -p 53 1.1.1.1
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-05 11:20 UTC
Nmap scan report for one.one.one.one (1.1.1.1)
Host is up (0.0046s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

`STATE open` means that this port is open for traffic. But if you get `465/tcp filtered smtps` that means it's not going to work.

If the port is open to make sure anything listens on it ssh into your vm and check it with `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 465` and see if anything listens on that port. I checked port 80 and got:

```
wb@deb10-sample-www-page:~$ sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep *:80
nginx   7631     root    6u  IPv4  29349      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   7631     root    7u  IPv6  29350      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   7709 www-data    6u  IPv4  29349      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   7709 www-data    7u  IPv6  29350      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   7710 www-data    6u  IPv4  29349      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   7710 www-data    7u  IPv6  29350      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

---

### UPDATE

Your OS firewall settings are OK. Port 465 is open for both incoming and outgoing traffice.

You GCP firewall rules are also set in a correct way.

From the last screenshot I can clearly see that port 465 is in `closed` state that means nmap was able to connect and get a response from the OS but there's no app listening on it.

Issue is with your phpmailer configuration. I've found some usefull discussions on Stack that can help you out:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535294/mail-not-sending-with-phpmailer-over-ssl-using-smtp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596504/phpmailer-failing-with-ssl
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535280/sending-emails-from-port-465-makes-the-website-unresponsive-phpmailer